# How to test web components in Dart?

Tags: unit-testing, dart, dart-webui

There isn't much documentation insofar on web-ui testing in Dart. Two methods are available : a) run through Chrome's DumpRenderTree or b) a trick that consists of [loading the app as is and running the test code on top of it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14073897/378946). For trivial cases, the first option seems to be a bit tedious. So the latter option -- which in my case, doesn't work when it comes to load components.

With the following file structure:

```
test/
  main_test.html
  main_test.dart
web/
  main.html
  app.html
```

([all the files are listed in this gist](https://gist.github.com/nunobaba/5773150))

The following test set hangs on the second step.

```dart
main() {
  useShadowDom = true;

  test('Inline element is initially present.', () {
    var story = () => expect(query('#hdr'), isNotNull);
    Timer.run(expectAsync0(story));
  });

  test('Component is loaded.', () {
    var story = () => expect(query('#globe'), isNotNull);
    Timer.run(expectAsync0(story));
  });
}
```

How could the app component be loaded? More broadly, is there another method of testing web components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For web-ui test you have to query the shadow dom or the xtag (this) of the webcomponent that you whant to test instead of the "classic" dom.
Based on [TodoMVC code sample](https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/blob/master/example/todomvc/test/todomvc_listorder_shadowdom_test.html)

*With your code:*
A working version of this test is :

```dart
main() {
  useShadowDom = true;

  test('Inline element is initially present.', () {
    var story = () => expect(query('#hdr'), isNotNull);
    Timer.run(expectAsync0(story));
  });

  test('Component is loaded.', () {
    var root = query("span[is=x-app]").shadowRoot;
    var story = () => expect(root.query('#globe'), isNotNull);
    Timer.run(expectAsync0(story));
  });
}
```

and a test version without expectAsync should be:

```dart
main() {
  useShadowDom = true;

  Timer.run(() {
    test('Header element is initially present.', () {
      var hdr = query('#hdr');
      expect(hdr, isNotNull);
    });

    test('EchapApp component is loaded.', () {
      var root = query("span[is=x-app]").shadowRoot;
      var globe = root.query('#globe');
      expect(globe, isNotNull);
    });
  });
}
```

and finaly a version without shadow dom :

```dart
main() {
  //useShadowDom = true;

  Timer.run(() {
    test('Header element is initially present.', () {
      var hdr = query('#hdr');
      expect(hdr, isNotNull);
    });

    test('EchapApp component is loaded.', () {
      var root = query("span[is=x-app]").xtag;
      var globe = root.query('#globe');
      expect(globe, isNotNull);
    });
  });

}
```

For me this 3 codes are 100% pass on Dartium with 
Dart Editor version 0.5.20_r24275
Dart SDK version 0.5.20.4_r24275

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the karma-dart runner: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-dart

It even has a web components example.

```dart
library click_counter_test;

import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import '../web/out/xclickcounter.dart';

main() {
  test('CounterComponent.increment', () {
    var hello = new DivElement();
    var component = new CounterComponent.forElement(hello);
    expect(component.count, equals(0));
    component.increment();
    expect(component.count, equals(1));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not Dart specific, you can use Selenium for testing the UI. I believe some members of the Dart team have used Selenium as well to do UI testing.